# Trying to do a CURL Post to an ASP.NET Application

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I am not an ASP developer at all.

I am using Postman and am trying to do a simple POST to an ASP.NET application URL (above). In short, I am simply trying to POST to the 'Street' field and show a response.

The URL (above) initially has a 'disclaimer' page that I can get by using the cookie, `DISCLAIMER=1` in my request. So, when I get to the form where I can query addresses, I POST but nothing happens.

When inspecting the URL (above), the field for 'Street' has a HTML name of 'inpStreet' so when I set my Postman Params to `KEY = 'inpStreet'` and the VALUE to 'main'. Nothing happens when I click the 'Send' button in Postman.

**Here's the desired outcome:**

I want to get the results from the form in the URL (above) using Postman. In a browser, go to the URL (above), agree to the disclaimer and type 'main' in the 'Street' field and click 'Search'. That's it! Simple, right?

What am I missing? TIA!

**Project URL: https://property.sussexcountyde.gov/PT/search/CommonSearch.aspx?mode=ADDRESS**

Comment: I tried to make the request using Postman and nothing happens indeed. Does the ASP application have any documentation? Are there any headers that should be changed or set? Are you sure the ASP application functions correctly?

Comment: There's no documentation for the app. It's a simple government site that allows user's to query public data (i.e. addresses, owner info, etc). Not sure about the headers - I took a look at the inspector for the Form Elements and didn't see anything that stuck out as missing. The app does seem to be functioning properly as any request I make via the browser works as expected, without error. Head scratcher...

Comment: Right.. If there were some parameters missing you'd expect a response. Maybe with a status code 404, 400 or even 500. But there's no response at all, like there's no service available on the given URL